# Formally proving that $E(|X|) < \infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n) < \infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In other words, I have to prove that

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|f(x)dx < \infty \iff\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|\geq n) < \infty$
where $f(x)$ is the density function.

I know that the summation could be re-written as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(n\leq|X|< n+1)$
I feel like I'm close but I know this is not enough. What am I missing?

Any help would be apprieciated!

Comment: Perhaps you can start with the fact that $E(|X|)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(|X|=n)$.

Comment: My mistake for not mentioning it but X is a continous random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

observe that $$\mathbb{E} |X| \geq \sum n P(n \leq |X| < n+1)$$ (quite obvious) and that $$\mathbb{E} |X| \leq \sum (n+1) P(n \leq |X| < n+1)$$. now all you need to do is to show that the convergence of  $\sum (n+1) P(n \leq |X| < n+1)$ is the same as that of $\sum n P(n \leq |X| < n+1)$ - hope this answers your question, but feel free to pose additional questions if you're unsure with regards to some step

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first inequality should be $\geq$, right? Are both these inequalities together strong enough to prove the double-sided implication?

Comment: you're right, I changed to $\geq$. yeah, that's enough to prove equivalency as long as you show the last part - that the series with $(n+1)$ is essentialy the same as the one with $n$

Answer (score 4):

Let $n \in \Bbb N$. For $x \in [n-1,n]$, $P(|X| \ge n) \le P(|X| \ge x) \le P(|X| \ge n-1)$. So $$P(|X| \ge n) \le \int_{n-1}^n P(|X| \ge x)\, dx \le P(|X| \ge n-1).$$ Thus

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(|X| \ge n) \le \int_0^\infty P(|X| \ge x)\, dx \le \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(|X| \ge n-1)$$

i.e.,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(|X| \ge n) \le E(|X|) \le 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(|X| \ge n)$$

Therefore, $E(|X|) < \infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n =1}^\infty P(|X| \ge n) < \infty$.

Comment: In the first two lines how do we get $\int_0^\infty P(|X| \ge x)\, dx$ from $P(|X| \ge x)$?

Comment: It's because $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n P(|X| \ge x)\, dx = \int_0^\infty P(|X| \ge x)\, dx$.

Comment: :( still can't get it... ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but let $N$ be a positive integer and take the sum of the inequalities $P(|x| \ge n) \le \int_{n-1}^n P(|X| \ge x)\, dx \le P(|X| \ge n-1)$ from $n = 1$ to $N$ to get $$\sum_{n = 1}^N P(|X| \ge n) \le \int_0^N P(|X| \ge x)\, dx \le \sum_{n = 1}^N P(|X| \ge n-1)$$ Then take the limit as $N\to \infty$ to obtain the second line.

Comment: @kobe I don't quite understand you "i.e." part. Why is the middle  part equal to the expectation?

Comment: @Topoguy using Fubini's theorem, we have $$E(|X|) = E\,\int_0^\infty 1_{(x,\infty)}(|X|)\,dx = \int_0^\infty E(1_{(x,\infty)}(|X|))\, dx = \int_0^\infty P(|X|\ge x)\, dx.$$

Comment: @kobe I don't get why we can go from $P(|X|>x)\leq P(|X|>n-1)$ to $\int_{n-1}^n P(|X|>x)dx\leq P(|X|>n-1)$?

Comment: @Wave Since $P(|X| > x) \le P(|X| > n-1)$ for all $x\in [n-1,n]$, then $\int_{n-1}^n P(|X| > x)\, dx \le \int_{n-1}^n P(|X| > n-1)\, dx = P(|X| > n-1)$.

Comment: @kobe perfekt thanks!